# Using CountVectorizor in FeatureUnion to use hetorogenious features

Tags: python, text, pipeline, countvectorizer

I have a text classification problem and want to add two features. The data I have is the reviews of movies (the imbd dataset). I want to use two features as input variable to classify the reviews into either a positive or negative sentiment. The two features are: Review-length (so the words used) and Bag-of-words representation of the review.

So the other thing is that I want to complete this using the `FeatureUnion` object in sklearn. So I figured out how to do it without, by using `hstack` in order to concatenate two sparse matrices. But as a learning purpose I am curious how to do it with `FeatureUnion` as I can not get my way around.

The resources I used until now:

- [Michelle Fullwood - Using Pipelines and FeatureUnions in scikit-learn](http://michelleful.github.io/code-blog//2015/06/20/pipelines/)
- [Zac Stewart - Using scikit-learn Pipelines and FeatureUnions](http://zacstewart.com/2014/08/05/pipelines-of-featureunions-of-pipelines.html)
- [Julie Michelman - Pandas, Pipelines, and Custom Transformers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFaadIqWlAg)

Until now I have the following code:

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# Instantiate pipeline: pl
pl = Pipeline([
        ('union', FeatureUnion(
            transformer_list = [
                ('numeric_features', Pipeline([
                    ('extract', ColumnExtractor(cols)),
                    ('length', AverageWordLengthExtractor())
                ])),
                ('text_features', Pipeline([
                    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer())
                ]))
             ]
        )),
        ('clf', LinearSVC())
    ])
```

The custom Transformers:

```
class AverageWordLengthExtractor(TransformerMixin):
    """Takes in dataframe, extracts road name column, outputs average word length"""

    def review_length(self, review):
        """Helper code to compute length of a review"""
        return len(review.split())

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        """Returns `self` unless something different happens in train and test"""
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        """The workhorse of this feature extractor"""
        return X.apply(self.review_length)
```

and another custom Transformer:

```
class ColumnExtractor(TransformerMixin):
    """Takes in dataframe, extracts road name column, outputs average word length"""

    def __init__(self, cols):
        self.cols = cols

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        """Returns `self` unless something different happens in train and test"""
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        """The workhorse of this feature extractor"""
        return X[self.cols]
```

Please note that the X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test datasets are transformed into a pandas DataFrame, so the input of the pipeline will be a dataframe.

What I think goes wrong is with the `CountVectorizer`, as this outputs a sparse matrix. Should I make my own custom transformer in the type of `CountVectorizer`, so it would return an dataframe instead? If so, isn't this very computationally expensive working with large corpus? I really could use some help I have the idea I do not get the complete picture working with `CountVectorizer` in a `FeatureUnion` class.

Comment: What is the exact problem that you have? The `FeatureUnion` transformer is capable of dealing with sparse matrices, so that should not cause any trouble. Maybe you can provide some reproducible example with sample data and any error messages that might occur.

Comment: So whats the question? Are you getting any error? Is the output not as you wanted?

Comment: By the way I can see multiple points of failure in the posted code. First, you are using `CountVectorizer()` on all of your data (not selecting columns as you are doing above it). Second the `AverageWordLengthExtractor()` will in most cases return a series (1-d) which FeatureUnion will not be able to handle properly